# JavaScript addEventListener requires 2 clicks to fire function

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

Here's a little demo of what I'm experiencing:

http://jsfiddle.net/jajV6/

And here are the code snippets:

HTML:

```
<div id="frame">
<div class="bead col_a" id="a1"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frame {
position: relative;
height: 205px;
}

.bead {
position: absolute;
background: black;
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.bead:hover {
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#a1 {
top: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
var a1 = document.getElementById("a1");

function fiveToggle(bead1) {
    if (bead1.style.top === "0px"){
    bead1.style.top = "25px";
    } else {
    bead1.style.top = "0px";
    }
}

a1.addEventListener("click", function(){ fiveToggle(a1); }, false);
```

The idea is to have the position of the bead shift either up or down when clicked. To toggle, in other words. But adding an if/else statement to the function that achieves this makes the clickable item require two clicks before it will move. After that initial extra click, the bead moves with one click as desired. If I remove the if/else statement from the function that repositions the bead and add code that simply moves it (without a conditional check), then it works as desired. I find this curious. Would someone kindly explain to me why this behaves this way?

Comment: `bead1` doesn't have `top` defined, so it moves to 0px first. Use `console.log(bead1.style.top);` at the beginning of the `fiveToggle` function to see its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with addEventListener, you have to add one condition `|| bead1.style.top == ""` because bead1.style.top is empty by default:

```
function fiveToggle(bead1) {
    if (bead1.style.top == "0px" || bead1.style.top == ""){
        bead1.style.top = "25px";
    } else {
        bead1.style.top = "0px";
    }
}
```

You can do that using css too, setting the initial top value to 0px

Comment: He wants to know WHY it behaves that way.  Not how he can get around it.

Comment: bead1.style.top is empty by default and bead1.style.top == "0px" is false

Comment: @Ragnar Interesting... In my CSS I set a1 to have a top value of 0px. Are you saying that when I then pass a1 into the fiveToggle function (as bead1), it doesn't take the CSS into account? Evidently not. I guess the question is, if a1 is defined in CSS, then passed into a function as bead1, does it not carry its properties into the function?

Comment: @HunterMacDermut You are right, when we set top:0px via css it doesn't work, it seams to be a bug. Even if you set top:10px it doesn't work. But if you use jQuery it work fine. Use this code to get 'top' attribute: $('#a1').css('top')